# Primitive conversion from Kotlin to Java

Tags: java, kotlin

When trying to call a java method (constructor in this case) that accepts the type: **java.lang.Double?**

*Example (AuthRequestModel is a Java modal):*

```
AuthRequestModel(amount = 10.toDouble())
```

*Resolves with error:*

**Type mismatch. Required: Java.lang.Double? Found: Kotlin.Double**

What is the correct way of converting from **Kotlin** Double (or any other primitive) to **Java**?

For now, I added a conversion method that looks like so:

*Imp:*

```
fun Double.asJava(): java.lang.Double = this as java.lang.Double
```

*Usage:*

```
  AuthRequestModel(amount = 10.toDouble().asJava())
```

But this is force casting, and I would assume there is a native way of achieving the same result...

Comment: Are you describing the reality? If AuthRequestModel was a Java class, AFAIK, you wouldn't be able to use named parameters to call its constructor. My guess is that AuthRequestModel is a Kotlin class which has been poorly translated to Kotlin.

Comment: @JBNizet wow. you are right, nice catch... Change to an answer an I will approve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `AuthRequestModel` was a Java class, you wouldn't be able to use named parameters to call its constructor. My guess is that `AuthRequestModel` is a Kotlin class which has been poorly translated to Kotlin. Fix the translation so that it uses a plain `Double` or `Double?`.

Comment: "If AuthRequestModel was a Java class, you wouldn't be able to use named parameters to call its constructor." If it's compiled with `-parameters`, it should work. At least Scala supports it, I'd expect Kotlin to support it as well.

Comment: AFAIK, Kotlin decided not to support this because argument names in Java are an implementation detail, not part of the signature of a method. Changing the name of an argument is a backward compatible change in Java, and allowing to use named parameters for Java methods would potentiallybreak the code every time the Java libray author changes its mind about compilation options and parameter names. See https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/what-is-the-reason-for-not-allowing-named-arguments-for-java-interop/4571

Comment: I see, thanks! Maybe if Java finally enables it by default it'll change in the future...

Answer (score 2):

According to [kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html)

> Java's boxed primitive types are mapped to nullable Kotlin types:

```
Java type              Kotlin type
java.lang.Byte         kotlin.Byte?
java.lang.Short        kotlin.Short?
java.lang.Integer      kotlin.Int?
java.lang.Long         kotlin.Long?
java.lang.Character    kotlin.Char?
java.lang.Float        kotlin.Float?
java.lang.Double       kotlin.Double?
java.lang.Boolean      kotlin.Boolean?
```

That means you can just cast to nullable kotlin.Double? and use your java target natively.